# error #1055 yet another contains nonaggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I know a lot of questions have already been answered on this one but I still cant wrap my head around it why the following isnt working.
My main goal was to join a price and product table and select the cheapest price for each product based on each 3 factors.

For quick testing I went ahead and just filtered my price table which contains the a ref to my corresponding product, price, rrp and some columns for knowing when to apply which price.

```
SELECT product_ref_id, price, rrp WHERE (.... filter by attributes ....).
```

This works fine, but for consistency I get at least 2 rows. Thing is I want to get the cheapest price BUT I also need the rrp for displaying. So I went ahead and made:

```
SELECT product_ref_id, min(price), rrp WHERE (.... filter by attributes ....) GROUPY BY product_ref_id
```

Which gives me error #1055:

#1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'igros_backend.prices.rrp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Once I leave out the rrp select it works just fine, but I cant get my rrp then (the rrp can differ on the results as well). If I put the rrp into my group_by I get more than 1 result per id which is also not the way it is intended to be.
And as I read disabling the only_full_group_by is not the way to go.
Any help where my brain is going wrong here?
Could this be due to the fact that not all rrp have a set price but can also be null?
Edit: As a matter of fact each entry has its own id, so in my opinion the most logical way when using subqueries would be to prefilter the table by my conditions, join on the id with the price and uvp, then select by my min(price) and group by after.

Further edit: as I just cant get it to work I will explain all in more detail.
This is my table

```
id    product_id_ref    filterOption   filterOptionCode    price   rrp
```

For each product_id_ref there might be more than one or one entry in the table.
I have to check if the filterOption applies (this depends on the logged user). So I get at least 1 result back, mostly 2 but more are also possible.

Which works fine... If I just want the price and product_ref_id back.
Might the problem be that I get back the same product_id_ref multiple times?

Comment: If a product_ref_id has several rrp values, which one do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it when you find MIN price in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  sub.product_ref_id, 
  sub.price, 
  sub.product_id,
  sub.id,
  main.rrp
FROM
  {table} AS main
JOIN 
  (SELECT 
     product_ref_id, 
     MIN(price),
     product_id,
     MIN(id)
   WHERE 
     [... filter by attributes ....]
   GROUP BY 
     product_ref_id, product_id
  ) AS sub ON sub.product_ref_id = main.product_ref_id AND sub.price = main.price AND sub.id = main.id AND sub.product_id = main.product_id;
```

So in a subuquery you get the field with min price and you use this resultset to join with original table records. This way you can get the rest of the fields for the row with MIN price.

Comment: While the queries on its own work without any issues (if I add the table to the subquery of course) it sadly get #1054 - Unknown column 'product_ref_id' in 'field list' when I apply that query

Comment: Might be missing aliases issue. I edited the answer, you can try now.

Comment: works but I totally forgot the problem: there are many entries for one product that contain the same prices. Sadly we dont have influence on that. My gut tells me the best solution would be to get the id (which is unique) of the row with the lowest price. I, however, havent figured out how to get there as I would need to select product_id and id which then gives me way more results back (logically)

Comment: @Progressive you can add it to the select result and subquery as well. I modified the query in a way it should give you these fields too. Hoping, I got you right.

Comment: All of a sudden I feel dum as hell. that little MIN(id) was the thing that made all the difference as I used it without the MIN() ... is there any resource to read up on that? thank you very much for that.

Comment: Not sure of a resource, you need to google it up. But if you need to add another column to your grouped result you need to apply aggregation function on it. And if it does not do any harm you can use MIN, MAX which suit in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> My main goal was to join a price and product table and select the cheapest price for each product based on each 3 factors.

The simplest method is to use window functions.  The looks something like this:

```
select pp.*
from (select pr.*, p.*,
             min(pr.price) over (partition by pr.product_id) as min_price
      from price pr join
           product p
           on pr.product_id = p.product_id
     ) pp
where price = min_price
```

Your question does not elaborate on what the data really looks like, but this is the structure for joining two tables and taking the smallest value by some unit (such as product).